# Подключенный шрифт печатает только английский (css)

Tags: html, css, шрифты

У меня проблема с отображением русских символов при подключении шрифта. Работают только английские.
Уже сталкивался с этой проблемой и решил ее, но не могу вспомнить как.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте фрагменты кода в виде текста, а не картинки.

Comment: Ну так шрифт без поддержки Кириллицы, скорее всего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможен вариант что у тебя это не web шрифт. Смотри в инспекторе браузера, он у тебя вообще определяется или просто тот который по умолчанию стоит?

**UPD** Да, я все понял, как видно по скриншотам он прогонялся через Font Squirrel, и этот шрифт не подходит для web, найди лучше на Goole Fonts похожий или другой альтернативный или же такой но сделанный специально для web.

Если через Font Squirrel не помогло и подобные ему сервисы, значит это чисто для типографии набор шрифтов и для верстальщиков он не годится. Но бывает что существуют в нескольких вариантах для типографии и web дизайнеров, иначе используй другой похожий.